# Find earliest date using the digits 0-9 only once in the format DD/MM HH:MM:SS

Tags: algorithm, date

Need an algorithm to find the earliest date using the digits 0-9 only once in the format DD/MM HH:MM:SS. The actual answer would be: 26/03 17:48:59

Comment: brute force 10! possibilities is still computeable in reasonable time. You can even do it wisely starting from months with lowest characters, and terminate when you first find a feasible solution.

Comment: No, you don't need an algorithm -- you already have the answer to the question.

Comment: I know the answer, but trying to calculate it using program.

Comment: My friend got it in an interview. So trying tho find the easy approach.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way - generate all permutations of [0...9] and check if they are a valid date.

10 ! = 3 628 800

If you want to improve the efficiency, backtracking would help. In this case, it's just a simple constraint satisfaction problem, the number of valid dates is much less than the number of permutations.  Furthermore, you can consider them in order of lowest month, then lowest day, etc.

For example

01 doesn't work because the first digit of the time (10s hours) needs to be 0 or 1
02 doesn't work because the first digit of the time must be 1 now and the date can only be 0,1,2 in February.

And so on.

FWIW - There are only 769 valid dates

```
import datetime
import itertools

count = 1
for perm in itertools.permutations( range(10) ):

    i = 0;
    day = perm[i]+perm[i+1]*10
    i+=2
    month = perm[i]+perm[i+1]*10
    i+=2
    hour =  perm[i]+perm[i+1]*10
    i+=2
    minute =  perm[i]+perm[i+1]*10
    i+=2
    second =  perm[i]+perm[i+1]*10
    try:
        print datetime.datetime( 2012, month, day, hour, minute, second)
        count+=1
    except:
        pass

print count
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). You might want to work with the date format MM/DD HH:MM:SS first and later convert your answer. In this format, the lexicographically smallest valid date string will be the answer you seek, so if you search systematically, the first valid date you find would be the solution.

Essentially, you search space has 12 x 31 x 24 x 60 x 60 of mostly valid dates. So, your constraints include:

```
month < 13
day   < 32
hour  < 24
minutes < 60
seconds < 60
occurrence(date, i) == 1 for each i = 0 to 9
```

You could then use a [backtracking search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to proceed systematically through the search space.